# Eclipse file type dependent print margin?

Tags: eclipse

I know that you can set the print margin in Eclipse, but if I want different line-width settings for different file types? Say, 100 for .java, and 80 for .txt? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible. Not with the UI, at least.

I think that Eclipse editors could all have different settings but it seems that the usual implementation behaviour is to set common parameters in *General/Editors/Text Editors* and only specific properties in language-dependent editors (like *Java/Editor*).

Comment: +1 Eclipse associates file types with particular Editors (see Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations, and Window > Preferences > General > Content Types). You can usually set some idea of line length in the Editor's preference panel.